# How to open a browser from terminal

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

Can anyone tell me how to open a browser from the Terminal on a Mac?

Answer (score 67):

Just enter

```
open "http://www.google.com"
```

And it'll open it in your default browser

Comment: open -a "Firefox" "http://www.superuser.com" will open the link in any other application you specify.

Answer (score 14):

To have your OS X machine open the default browser to a specific page, you just have to type:

```
open http://example.com/
```

Simple as pie.  The `open` command was introduced way back on the NeXT operating system, and in [its modern incarnation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html), uses LaunchServices to determine the appropriate application to open the given file or URL.

Answer (score 7):

I just use

```
open -a safari
```

to open a browser (safari as an e.g. here).

---

The `open -a` stand for *"opens with the specified application"*. It is case-insensitive, so you can open Finder like

```
open -a finder
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to open the browser, without a URL, use open with just the browser name:

> open /Applications/Safari.app
>
> open /Applications/Firefox.app

etc.

You can use open to open any application by name.

Answer (score 1):

If the default application for opening HTML files has been changed to a text editor, `open test.html` would  open the file in the editor.

You could open it in the default browser with `open test.html -a "$(VERSIONER_PERL_PREFER_32_BIT=true perl -MMac::InternetConfig -le 'print +(GetICHelper "http")[1]')"`.